# Apache Cassandra overwhelming bandwidth overhead

Tags: cassandra

while testing Apache Cassandra, I inserted 1000 rows of data. I allow it to propagate to the other machine on LAN. This is a 2 machine cluster. I monitor the network connection between the two machine. The total data I expected to flow between the two servers should be around 25Mb including all column names, column values and timestamps). But the actual data sent and received between them was an whopping 362Mb!! Anybody knows why is there such an overwhelming overhead? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.  It's probably easier to figure out what's going on if you look at a single operation at a time, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the gossip protocol implemented to handle things like cluster membership, management and replication.